# Bootstrap 4 не работают классы!

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap4

Подключил bootstrap 4.1. Работают простые классы типа `.container`, `.col`, `.col-3` и т.д.  Но не работают `.flex-start` `.justify-content` и т.д. в чем дело может быть? Я даже не знаю где искать проблему, потому, что все подключено, работает, если бы не правильно подключил то никакой бы класс не работал.

Comment: а про `row` забыли? `col-` должны находится в `row` блоке

Comment: нет про row не забыл, да уже тупо копирую всю разметку с сайта bootstrap и пишу классы , не работает, это просто жесть

Comment: приложите код, то место где не работает

Comment: <div class="row">
     <div class="col-5 flex-last">Стоит слева должен встать спарва </div>
     <div class="col-7 flex-first">Стоит справа, должент встать слева</div>
    </div>

Comment: @Игорь _flex-last_ , _flex-first_, нет таких классов в четвертом бутсрапе. Вот список всех классов - http://bootstrapcreative.com/resources/bootstrap-4-css-classes-index

Comment: хорошо    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">1111111111111</div>
     <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">2222222222222</div>
    </div>
   </div>

Comment: .col-md-push-4    .col-md-push-8   такой то есть? не работает!!!!  и вообще любой готовый код вставляю из тех , что предлагается, не работают!!!

Comment: <table style="height: 100px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align-baseline">baseline</td>
      <td class="align-top">top</td>
      <td class="align-middle">middle</td>
      <td class="align-bottom">bottom</td>
      <td class="align-text-top">text-top</td>
      <td class="align-text-bottom">text-bottom</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>   ЭТИ СРАБОТАЛИ

Comment: <p class="text-success">.text-success</p>      РАБОТАЕТ

Comment: @Игорь где вы берете эти примеры? я в доках bs4 не видел такого вообще. Исколесил эти доки вдоль и в поперек. Задавайте вопросы тем у кого вы берете эти примеры.

Comment: все спасибо я нашел, что нужно , сори , за потраченное время